# I have developed a java desktop application for windows i need to make exe file

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, desktop-application, javac

I have developed a java desktop application for windows i need to make exe file, I don't know procedures to develop exe from my project

Comment: Please consider using the search function. This topic has been answered several times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click the desired project and choose Package as > EXE Installer from the context menu (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html#instse)

Note: The IDE creates an EXE installer only if Inno Setup is installed and added to the system Path variable (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html#tool)

When the EXE installer is ready, it is placed in the /dist/bundles/ directory.

Comment: Do i need to pay money to oracle for its usage

Comment: I believe it's free although I have not used it.

Comment: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php --> "Is it really free of charge, even for commercial use?

Yes, it may be used completely free of charge, even when deploying commercial applications. However if you wish to show your appreciation and support its development you can make a donation."

Comment: While you are in this category, I suggest you go ahead and download http://wixtoolset.org/. It covers Windows installation packages. That way, when you create your exe you can also create your MSI.

Answer (score 0):

This answer extends @pruntlar answer.

> Since you will be making Windows applications I suggest you also look into Windows Installer Package(MSI). The Netbean link @pruntlar provided should also cover this topic. The tools needed are available free here: http://wixtoolset.org/

Answer (score 0):

Why not [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

It's written in Java and it can create a .exe file that you run your jar file or it can create a .exe file with your jar file inside it.

Comment: Sir i have got exe file but in normal software installation procedures there are accept license, location selection etc in installation file how can i make this exe file as an installation file